# Propose tag wiki is not working.

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-bydesign

When i click propose tag wiki nothing happening.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We don't support localized meta tag wiki changes at this time; we centralize those at the network hub at http://meta.stackoverflow.com and push them out to the rest of the network periodically.

Comment: So there should be message like ( We don'nt support localized meta tag)

Comment: Or, you know, maybe don't show a button that doesn't perform the action it says it does.